# What does "baited anticipation" mean?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

A song i was hearing has this line :

> You stare at me with **baited anticipation**

what does this mean ?

Comment: Probably [bated](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bated).

Comment: @ Michael Harvey thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you heard was 'bated', from an archaic (16th C) word meaning 'restrained'  If someone has bated breath, it means that they are too anxious or excited to breathe freely. The spelling 'baited' can sometimes be found, but most authorities consider this an error. Also in modern English it only used this way (about breath) so it is not really appropriate to speak of 'bated anticipation'.

[Bated (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bated)

Comment: The literal meaning of _with bated breath_ is _too anxious or excited to breathe freely_ (Oxford Dictionaries says 'late 16th century: from the past participle of obsolete bate ‘restrain’.' So it's not really appropriate to speak of 'bated anticipation'.

Comment: @KateBunting: The usage ***bated anticipation*** [certainly does exist](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bated+anticipation%22) - it's just very rare [compared to ***bated breath***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bated+anticipation%2Cbated+breath&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbated%20anticipation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbated%20breath%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers People may have used it, but it's a misuse of the word _bated_.

Comment: Agreed - ***bated = abated = lessened / suspended*** certainly makes sense for ***holding one's breath** in anticipation*. But what would "bated / suspended" anticipation *itself* be? Cautious optimism?